# react js conteneditable not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very simple component to add comments. The `<p>` tag is contenteditable. However, when I visit the page, the `<p>` is not being contenteditable. If I click inside the `<p>` nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? How can I make the `<p>` contenteditable? Please help.

```
export default class AddComment extends React.Component {    
    render() {
        return(
            <div id="add_comment">
                <div id="divLeft">
                    <p id="comment" contenteditable="true"></p>
                </div>
                <div id="divRight">
                    <input type="submit" value="Comment" id="submit"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React you have to use [`contentEditable`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tags-and-attributes.html#html-attributes) instead of `contenteditable`

```js
class AddComment extends React.Component {    
  render() {
    return(
      <div id="add_comment">
        <div id="divLeft">
          <p id="comment" contentEditable="true"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="divRight">
          <input type="submit" value="Comment" id="submit"/>
         </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AddComment />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```